# To create new list using existing one and splitting strings using regular expressions and specific letter inside the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have this sample list:

```
list1= ['**Tracheobionta Vascular** n.a.m.e T/V trachea ',
 'Spermatophyta SEED (name. F.P.S.)',
‘/Magnoliophyta Flowering/’,
‘Rudbeckia coneflower/ N-A-M-E.: /Rud_beckia’
]
```

And this is what I need:

```
list2= [( 'Tracheobionta Vascular’ ,   ‘T/V trachea '),
( 'Spermatophyta SEED, ‘F.P.S’),
(‘Magnoliophyta Flowering’, None),
(‘Rudbeckia coneflower’, ‘Rud beckia’)
]
```

I am not sure how to approach this... I do not need the code just how should I approach this.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first of all need to clean up the strings and the simple use the following:

```
outputList = []
for str in list2:
    strList = str.split('name')
    tu = tuple(strList)
    outputList.append(tu)

print(outputList)
```

I used the following piece of code to clean up your strings:

```
list2 = []
for aStr in list1:
    aStr1 = aStr.replace('*', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('-', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace(':', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('(', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace(')', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('/', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('NAME', 'name')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('n.a.m.e', 'name')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('. ', '')
    aStr1 = aStr1.replace('_', ' ')
    list2.append(aStr1)
```

Here is a cope of my output:

```
[('Tracheobionta Vascular ', ' TV trachea '), ('Spermatophyta SEED ', 'F.P.S.'), ('Magnoliophyta Flowering',), ('Rudbeckia coneflower ', 'Rud beckia')]
```

Comment: nice approach, i was stuck with using regular expressions... :/. thank you so much

Comment: It's my please -- you can modify it to suit you